# How can I handle expression in text box depend upon check box in java script?

Tags: javascript, html

My question is if the check box is checked the value inserted inside the text box gives a square. If it is 3 inside the text box, after clicking on checkbox the result have to be 9 in text box.

**Kindly resolve it using JavaScript and HTML only.**

```js
function myfun() {
    var a = document.getElementById("checkedid");
    var b;
    var c = document.getElementById("txtbox");
    
    if(a.checked == true){
        alert("Value will be doubled");
        b = c*c;
        document.myform.txt.value = b;
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="myform">
    TextBox<input type="text" value="" name="txt" id="txtbox">
    <br/>
    Check Box<input type="checkbox" name="checkbx" id="checkedid" onclick="myfun()">
</form>
```

Comment: This is a very basic question, kindly search other questions before asking if its already answered.

Comment: @Muhammad Kindly answer it if you know the "basics".

Comment: better if you read the rules for posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `var c = document.getElementById("txtbox");` with `var c = document.getElementById("txtbox").value;`. You have to get the value of from the `input`.

```js
function myfun() {
    var a = document.getElementById("checkedid");
    var b;
    var c = document.getElementById("txtbox").value;
    
    if(a.checked == true){
        alert("Value will be doubled");
        b = c*c;
        document.myform.txt.value = b;
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="myform">
    TextBox<input type="text" value="" name="txt" id="txtbox">
    <br/>
    Check Box<input type="checkbox" name="checkbx" id="checkedid" onclick="myfun()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function myfun() {
        var a = document.getElementById("checkedid");
        var b;
        var c = document.getElementById("txtbox");
        
        if(a.checked == true){
            var temp = c.value
            b = temp * temp;
            c.value = b;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```html
    <form name="myform">
        TextBox<input type="text" value="" name="txt" id="txtbox">
        <br/>
        Check Box<input type="checkbox" name="checkbx" id="checkedid" onclick="myfun()">
    </form>
```

Here you are getting elemnet from ID. You need to **perform square operation on value not on element**

Use

**c.Value instead of only c**

```
function myfun()
   {
      var a = document.getElementById("checkedid");
      var c = document.getElementById("txtbox");
      var b;
      if(a.checked == true){
           //Use c.Value not c
           var temp = c.value;
           b = temp * temp;
           c.value = b;
           return false;
           }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. The only assumption is that the textbox has a value.

```
function myFunc() {
    var chk = document.getElementById("checkedid");            
    if (chk.checked == true) {
        var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtbox").value);
        var result = x * x;
        document.myform.txt.value = result.toString();
        return false;
    }
}
```